# Microsoft WCF - SOAP messaging protocol

Tags: wcf, jax-ws

is that correct that the default Web Service created using WCF will have WSDL but the message transmission required should not have SOAP tags like 
<soap:envelope>, <soap:header>, <soap:body> ?

Are they still using SOAP 1.1 in this case then?

And then, how can I create another web service using JAX-WS that is following this standard?

Thanks a bunch,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you're asking but if you're trying to invoke java based services (Apache, Metro, etc...) with a WCF client, take a look at the [WCF Express Interop bindings](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Express%20Interop%20Bindings).

Comment: hi, our system (Java) needs to talk with another system (.NET) created by another vendor. They mentioned they are using SOAP 1.1 web service level (with WSDL and so on), but they do not want all the SOAP standard protocols (SOAP envelope, header and body tag). They mentioned that it's the best practice in .NET world (using WCF). Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know how the vendor can say they're using soap at all if they want to remove the required elements like envelope, header & such. It is absolutely incorrect to say this is normal when using WCF.  It's one thing for a vendor to call moving standard XML over HTTP a "web service" but WCF is not really designed to do that. WCF's implementation of the WS-Security standard sometimes causes problems with Java based services or client (and vice versa) but WCF does create standards compliant soap messages.